# ffmpeg: save an mp3 part repeated 3 times

Tags: loops, ffmpeg, repeat

```
ffmpeg -ss 20s -t 30 -i original.mp3 -acodec copy output.mp3
```

This command is cutting 30 seconds of an mp3 file and i also want to repeat the 30s loop 3 times and save to the output.mp3 
Is there anyway to do this in ffmpeg?

Answer (score 2):

Simple method is to extract the segment:

```
ffmpeg -ss 20 -t 30 -i original.mp3 -c copy temp.mp3
```

Then use `-stream_loop`:

```
ffmpeg -stream_loop 2 -i temp.mp3 -c:v copy -c:a copy output.mp3
```

- Use at least FFmpeg 4.0.
- If it sounds bad between loops remove `-c:a copy` from command #2.
- If you want to do it in one command see the aloop filter in [Repeat/loop Input Video with ffmpeg?](https://video.stackexchange.com/q/12905)

Comment: @lutaoact This is an outdated answer. See `-stream_loop` option in [Repeat/loop Input Video with ffmpeg](https://video.stackexchange.com/a/12906/)

Comment: How would I prepend the full video to the 3 30-second loop? Can `-stream_loop` do that?

Comment: @stackexchange_account1111 `ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -stream_loop 2 -i temp.mp3 -map 0:v -map 1:a -c copy -shortest output.mkv`

Comment: Oh I've just noticed this is about mp3. I was trying to do full video followed by a 30-second segment of that video repeated 3 times.

Comment: @stackexchange_account1111 Should be asked as a new question at [su].